# How are can there be initial conditions in Bohmian mechanics that disobey the Born rule if Gleason's theorem is true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, born-rule, bohmian-mechanics

Gleason's theorem constrains the possible measures that are allowed on Hilbert spaces of dimension $\ge 3$. It is often said that Gleason's theorem essentially says that the Born rule is the probability measure consistent with quantum mechanics.

However, people often say that Bohmian mechanics requires initial conditions to have particles distributed according to the Born rule. Implicit in this statement is that there can be initial conditions that deviate away from the Born rule.

How does this square with Gleason's theorem?

Does this have to do with the fact that you are distributing countably many particles in your initial condition?

Comment: I don't think people, even those interested in Bohmian mechanics, are generally aware of Gleason's Theorem.